# Tester not working due to construtor parameter problems with array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, constructor, parameter-passing

Hope you guys can help me (I know this is alot im sorry)
below is my Customer class

```
import java.util.*;
public class Customer{
//fields
int id;
String firstName;
String lastName;
double lastYear;
ArrayList<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
//4 arg constructor
public Customer(String fN,String lN,int i){
id=i;
fN=firstName;
lN=lastName;
this.orderList=orderList;

}
//toString method
public String toString(){
return "Customer Information:"+"First Name: "+ firstName +" Last Name: "+ lastName+ "ID code"+ id; 
}
//AveragePayment method
public void AveragePayment(){
double total=0;
for(Order currentObj : orderList){
   total=total+currentObj.getTotalCost();
}
double avgCost = total / orderList.size();
}
}
```

this is my Order.java class

```
public class Order{
//fields
double salesTaxRate;
double price;
double shippingCost;
double total;
double salesTax;
//1 arg constructor
public Order(double set1){
salesTaxRate=set1;
price=0;
shippingCost=0;
total=0;
salesTax=0;
}
//setPrice method
public void setPrice(double p){
price=p;
salesTax=salesTaxRate*price;
double subTotal=(price+salesTaxRate);
if(subTotal<50){
shippingCost=0.8*subTotal;
}

else{
shippingCost=0;
}
}
//getTotalCost method
public double getTotalCost(){
   return total;
}
//setTotalCost
public void setTotal(double total){
this.total=total;
}

}
```

finally the tester

```
 import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        double avgPurchase; 

        Order[] lastYear = new Order[4];
    
        // I bought most stuff in Pennsylvania but..
        lastYear[0] = new Order(0.06);
        lastYear[1] = new Order(0.06);
        // I did send one thing to my mom in New York City and had to pay their sales tax...
        lastYear[2] = new Order(0.09);
        lastYear[3] = new Order(0.06);

            
        lastYear[0].setPrice(57.93);
        lastYear[1].setPrice(257.93);
        lastYear[2].setPrice(100.30);
        lastYear[3].setPrice(15.67);


        Customer me = new Customer("Christian" , "Turner" , 12321, lastYear);
        
        // okay! ready to go ! 

        System.out.println( me );

           avgPurchase = me.AveragePayment();
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
   
        System.out.println( "has spent an average of " + fmt.format(avgPurchase)  + " per purchase.");
}
}
```

im getting an error in my tester that says

```
Customer cannot be applied to given types;
        `Customer me = new Customer("Christian" , "Turner" , 12321, lastYear)`;
```

and also

```
Tester.java:32: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to double
           avgPurchase = me.AveragePayment()
```

[image]

As you can see im specifically instructed to modify my Customer class's constructor to allow the user to initalize the array. I believed i did just that however the tester is unable to populate the array. I believe i need an extra argument to specifically initalize the array however I'm confused on how to do so. Also I believe my AveragePayment method in my customer class is wrong because the data type is unable to convert from double to void, but i dont know how to go about fixing this. ***As this is an assignment i am unable to modify the tester in anyway*** Any help would be appreciated! I know its gotta be some little error im missing in the AveragePayment method, but the constructor error im literally clueless on how to solve it

Comment: Error #1 is referring to your constructor of customer.      `public Customer(String fN,String lN,int i){` you wrote it so Customer can only take in 3 arguments,  but the tester class you need to use is trying to pass in 4 arguments.  Error #2 the error is trying to tell you that your customer average function is returning void instead of a double.      `public void AveragePayment(){` you will need to change your average payment function to be public double `AveragePayment()`.  You will also need to use the `return` keyword to do this correctly,  but I will let you figure that one out.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework assignment I don't want to give you the answer, however most of this code is close to correct and you are not that far from solving the assignment.  I am going to try and break down some areas that are likely giving you issues.

To start, look at my comment about the two errors you are getting, hopefully that will help, if not you are welcome to respond and I can try and provide more clarity.

---

**Order List uses the wrong type**

`Customer.java` should use `Order[]` instead of `ArrayList<Order>`.  Since you cannot modify `Tester.java`, it is a good idea to match type you are given.  Look at how `Order[] lastYear` is initialized in `tester.java`

---

**Constructor Issues**

There is an additional issue with the constructor besides the incorrect number of arguments you mentioned in your question.  Take a close look at how you are doing the assignments inside this constructor.  *Think about which variable needs to change, put that one on the left and side so it gets assigned a new value*

```
//4 arg constructor
public Customer(String fN,String lN,int i){
  id=i;
  fN=firstName;
  lN=lastName;
  this.orderList=orderList;
}
```

---

**setPrice method**

Take a look at your `setPrice()` method in `Order.java`.  What should the outcome of this method be.  You are doing math correctly, but this method will not provide the outcome you are hoping for.

```
//setPrice method
public void setPrice(double p){
  price=p;
  salesTax=salesTaxRate*price;
  double subTotal=(price+salesTaxRate);

  if(subTotal<50){
    shippingCost=0.8*subTotal;
  }
  else{
    shippingCost=0;
  }
}
```